coc-rust-analyzer stopped providing hints on nvim
I have been using nvim with coc to code a simple rust project and it's been working well so far. However, from yesterday to today it just stopped providing autocompletion hints, it just suggests me the words that already appear in the file without any semantics.
The language server still works in some capacity, it still shows me syntax errors on the file i'm editing. I've done no updates of either rust-analyzer or vim or any plugin.
How can I solve this?
EDIT: after i solved the syntax errors on the project it started showing me autocomplete hints again, but only with the minimal "depth".
That is, if i have an enum called MyEnum with options A and B it and i start typing its name i will only see the MyEnum autocomplete option, where previously i would have seen MyEnum::A and MyEnum::B
EDIT 2: this is the structure of my project
src
├── app
│   └── ui.rs
├── app.rs
└── main.rs

the problem only occurs on the file ui.rs, the others have gone back to working correctly

Welcome to Vim! For the LSP server to provide suggestion it needs a valid code (a code that compile). Is your code compiling? Can you run the resulting binary?

In order to help you further it would be good if you could share a minimum rust program to illustrate the problem such that we can first reproduce it on our end.

yes, my code does compile. i tried opening a previous finished project to double-check and i'm still having the same problem

Thanks for the feedback! Could you share a simplified version of your code that demonstrate the problem such that we could try to reproduce your problem.

Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the solution using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

For the LSP server to be able to propose suggestion it needs that code is valid (e.g. compile). Otherwise it cannot deduce what are the valid objects, methods, member or functions that you can use. It can not also deduce the type of the variables.

my code does currently compile correctly

sorry if i took long to come back to the question. i found out the "problematic" file i was trying to edit was mostly a big vec![] macro, so it was probably being modified by the macro before being fed into the language server, interfering with autocompletion. your answer was correct, i didn't find a way to solve it directly but i will try to avoid writing sophisticated logic inside that macro to circumvent it

Thanks for the feedback :-)
